# Grails cannot handle spaces in image name

Tags: html, image, grails, gsp

My application needs to store and display images uploaded by users, but when the image has spaces in it's name (or any character that results in a invalid url) it is not shown in the web page.

The HTML that grails generate preserves the space in the names. I can't even go to the image directly by replacing the spaces with `%20` (error 404, but the image does exists and if I remove the space I can gain access to it)

Trying to force an encoding is useless, since it still preserves the spaces:

```
<g:img dir="someDir" file="${ image.encodeAsURL() }"/>
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: This confuses me: "if I remove the space I can gain access to it".  Does that mean the URL of the actual file has no spaces in it?  Looking at the file system are the spaces in the filename of the uploaded file?

Comment: There are spaces in the filename when I look at it in the file system. What I meant is that when I remove that space manually in the file system I can access the file with its URL, but if a space is present in the name, then not even encoding it with %20 works.